# sub DataFrame remain linked with the original one

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, extract

I have a list of DataFrame. I extracted in `pp` one of this DataFrame and I modified one column of `pp`. I remained shocked when I noted that the original DataFrame was modified as well.

I have an issue of quality because I do not know how many of my scripts are affected. Is there an explanation of this? What I did wrong?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


df3=df2=df1

predictions=[df1,df2,df3]

predictions
Out[96]: 
[   a  b  c
 0  1  2  3
 1  4  5  6
 2  7  8  9,
    a  b  c
 0  1  2  3
 1  4  5  6
 2  7  8  9,
    a  b  c
 0  1  2  3
 1  4  5  6
 2  7  8  9]

pp=predictions[0]

pp['a']= np.random.uniform(low=2, high=3, size=(len(pp['a']),))

predictions
Out[99]: 
[          a  b  c
 0  2.309992  2  3
 1  2.585460  5  6
 2  2.845087  8  9,
           a  b  c
 0  2.309992  2  3
 1  2.585460  5  6
 2  2.845087  8  9,
           a  b  c
 0  2.309992  2  3
 1  2.585460  5  6
 2  2.845087  8  9]
```

Comment: use `predictions[0].copy()` so that you will get copy of original dataframe. See aoout copy [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html).

Comment: `predictions` doesn't have a new memory space, it is just a reference. You need to create a copy!

Comment: When We create dataframe using df1=df2, all the data manipulation done in df1 will be implemented in df1 also.
try creating Dfs using df1=df2.copy()
Now when we do changes in DF1 DF2 will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You need copy, not reference so use [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()

predictions=[df1,df2,df3]

pp=predictions[0]
pp['a']= np.random.uniform(low=2, high=3, size=(len(pp['a']),))

print (predictions)
[          a  b  c
0  2.736182  2  3
1  2.996083  5  6
2  2.469578  8  9,    a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9,    a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9]
```